# Toshiba satellite u400 hardware buttons, which software?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers

I've recently installed Windows 7 64bit onto my Toshiba U400 laptop. I went over to the Toshiba support-download-drivers page and downloaded every driver that was missing.

I chose not to download bloated stuff, only the drivers. Win7 has much better control over hardware buttons out of the box then I had before.

But there is one thing that annoys me. I have hardware button on the laptop that is supposed to switch LEDs on/off. Windows 7 turns my sound on/off instead.

The second minor thing is, when I turn off sound by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (or light off button;-), the sound is off, however any slight touch with volume wheel turns it right back on! This is something that Ubuntu does also out of the box. I wonder what's the logic behind this.

Any lightweight solutions to these out there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it seems' that Toshiba's [value added package](http://eu.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/download_driver_details.jsp?service=EU&selCategory=2&selFamily=2&selSeries=198&selProduct=776&selShortMod=760&language=13&selOS=30&selType=all&yearupload=&monthupload=&dayupload=&useDate=null&mode=allMachines&search=&action=search&macId=&country=all&selectedLanguage=13&type=all&page=2&ID=69186&OSID=30&driverLanguage=42) is the only solution.